# How do I solve this issue. All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification. Found versions 26.1.0, 23.2.1

Tags: android, gradle

when I add the line below in my build.gradle (Module: app) file -

compile 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.0.0'

i am getting the error -

"All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 23.2.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)"

Help me solve the issue.

Below is the code of my build.gradle (Module:app) file -

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "learnturtle.payutrial"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: lazy answer: remove this line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` . done.

Comment: wouldn't it have any kind of bad effect?

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (23.2.1) and test app (25.4.0) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Comment: Got this error.

Comment: Either change 23.2.1 version 26.0.1 or vice versa.